# Creating a block programmatically in a theme on Drupal 8?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

So I was hoping to have my theme create special blocks for different parts of the front page so that they can be moved around easily later. I added the files to *mytheme/src/Plugin/Block/BlockName.php* but they never show up anywhere on the site or the block manager even after clearing cache.

Here's the code for one of my blocks (MediaPanel.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\mytheme\Plugin\Block\MediaPanel.
 */

namespace Drupal\mytheme\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides my custom block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "media_panel",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Media Panel"),
 *   category = @Translation("Blocks")
 * )
 */
class MediaPanel extends BlockBase {

/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return array('#markup' => 'hello world');
  }
}

?>
```

Do I *have* to use a module for creating Blocks? It would be inconvenient to have to make a module to create blocks that will be specific to my theme anyway.

Comment: If it's just markup/content, you could potentially save custom block content on install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Themes can't provide plugins.

Comment: Really? I know the Drupal 8 Bootstrap theme comes with an src/Plugin directory full of PHP class files. I was hoping it would be possible since I don't want to unpack the blocks' markup from the theme by having it go in the modules folder.

Comment: bootstrap does its own weird thing, it has special plugin types with special discovery that it implements itself. Those things actually *only* work with themes. Normal plugins do not.

Comment: Is there any work around to create a block problematically only for my theme?